# What does "as" stand for in the foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

When I read the code below, I think of it as for each name in class, but I was wondering if there is an actual meaning to "as" that is what does it actually stand for?

```
foreach ($class as $name) {...};
```

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as For each item in `$class` make the value available *as* `$name`.

Comment: It's a word. It doesn't stand for anything, it has its own meaning. You used "as" in your question, "I think of it as ...". That's the word.

Comment: @meagar I thought it might be an acronym for something.

Comment: No, it's just a word, like every other word in PHP. `if`, `else`, `function`, `for`, `while`, these are all English words with meanings that translate roughly to their use in programming.

Comment: @meagar Okay too bad, when I was just learning to program I found it difficult to remember that the data structure was on the left and value on the right, so I thought there was an easier way to remember this construct if "as" actually stood for something.

Comment: It's pretty easy if you understand it as an actual word that has a concrete meaning. Is English not your first language?

Comment: @meagar no it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything.

It simply means that the variable through which you will access the current item in the array will be accessed in the loop via that variable name.